# Can one use PCA scores to check for multivariate normality of the data?

Tags: pca, normality-assumption

How can you check multivariate normality, using the scores from the PCA (principal component analysis)? Or what can we expect about the scores if the data is multivariate normal distributed?

Answer (score 5):

If the original data is multivariate normal then the PCA scores will be as well (any linear combination of normals is normal).  But the reverse is not guaranteed.

In fact I would expect that something that is not multivariate normal (but not hugely different) would still result in PCA scores (at least some of them) that looked more normal than the original due to the same ideas as the Central Limit Theorem (there may be a specific CLT for this).  Since the PCA scores are in a sense a weighted average of other variables I would expect them to be more normal than the original.

There exist examples of multivariate distributions that have Normal margins, but are not Multivariate Normal.  The PCA scores are a rotation of this data, but the rotation will still likely have normal margins (so the individual PCA scores would look normal) but still be non multivariate normal in the same way (just rotated).

So I would not be comfortable saying anything about the multivariate normality of a dataset (other than possibly "normality is not ruled out") based on the PCA scores, no matter how normal they may look.

Comment: +1. But regarding your first and last paragraphs: I guess what you are saying is that if PCA scores are [univariate] normal, then the data are not necessarily multivariate normal. This if of course true. But if the PCA scores are *multivariate* normal, then the data are of course also multivariate normal. So I find the last paragraph, as currently stated, possibly misleading.

Comment: The fact that scores are weighted averages gives us no reason to suppose they will look normal at all! Note that at most one score's weights will all be positive; all the others will involve negative weights. In fact, PCA's ability to detect clusters relies on its tendency to perform in the *opposite* way: many PCs can be highly non-normal even when the original variables look close to normal.

Comment: I am still not clear on the answer even after your comments. Greg Snow stated that "any linear combination of normals is normal". Is there any evidence to this claim? If the initial data is multivariate normal, is each PC guaranteed to be univariate normal or multivariate normal or none of them? Also, can you suggest me a resource on this specific topic? I am pretty confused as this article (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cem.1147/abstract) suggests PCA transformation makes the data even more normal.

Comment: Directly quoting the author (Alexey L. Pomerantsev) from the article: `In our opinion, as the
PCA subspace is formed by the linear combinations of vectors $x_j$ ,
the scores t a could be viewed more ‘normal’ than the initial
variables. Therefore, ${\chi}^2$-distribution seems to be a preferred
alternative to F-distribution.`

Comment: @theGD, My go to reference is "Linear Models in Statistics" by Rencher and Schaalje (I may be biased, both authors are friends of mine).  In than book, theorem 4.4a states that the linear combinations of normals is normal, complete with proof.  Other similar texts will probably have similar proofs.

Comment: @GregSnow just to clarify, you meant "linear combinations of normals *which are jointly multivariate-normal* are normal", right? (By the way, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition actually gives that as a definition of a multivariate normal distribution)

Comment: The question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/289168/215801 seems very related to this discussion, as it asks about a claim (in https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387954424) that CLT might be used to show that PCs are approximately normal.

Comment: @orenmn, yes, I was originally thinking independent normals (which would be one form of multivariate normal), but multivariate normal would be the same.